# Unity3d Android build failed: Moving file failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I tried to build Unity3d with my own Android plugin and I got this error:

Moving `Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/iap-release/classes.jar` to `Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/iap-release/libs/classes.jar`: No such file or directory

I checked the `Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/iap-release/classes.jar` and the file exists.